# INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jax-ws, tomcat7, tomcat6

I'm been trying to deployed a simple web service on tomcat, but I have not success and it always return me 404 error.

I used the codes from this example:

- http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2011/01/20/jax-ws-web-services-maven-tomcat/
- http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/jaxwsExample.zip

JAX-WS not being initialized:[image]

[image]

So my ws is set up right? But I'm really out of clue why it is still not working.

Thank you for your time,

Droid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current settings, try in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/jaxwsExample-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/HelloWs
```

You can see the problem (in the first link):

> Now we just build the project with maven by `mvn clean install`, **rename it to `jaxwsExample.war`** (we can do that automatically in maven, but omit it for simplicity) and deploy it to the Tomcat.

So, in the `pom.xml` add the `finalName`:

```
<project ...>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>dk.sorokin.maksim</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxwsExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>JAX-WS Example</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <finalName>jaxwsExample</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I want to add to this that `http://` is very important for it to work. Just `localhost:8080/context/service` does NOT work, while `http://localhost:8080/context/service` DOES. Subtle detail that makes all the difference...